# Rails: Has Many... Through Syntax Issue With Where Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

So I have two models, `users` and `services`. `Users` that `check` a `service` basically bookmarks it, so I want to access them via `user.checks`.  Now there can be different relationships between a user and service, that's why I placed the `where` clause to make sure the `relationship_type` is `check`.

The Code

```
 has_many :checks, through: :user_services, source: :service, dependent: :destroy, -> { where relationship_type: 'check' }
```

The Error

```
/app/models/user.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
```

It's a syntax issue and I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a hash as parameter to a method, you can suppress the `{}` only when the hash is the last (or only) parameter passed. In this case, you pass a lamba after it, so you must explicitly write the hash as

```
has_many :checks, { through: :user_services, source: :service, dependent: :destroy }, -> { where relationship_type: 'check' }
```

Comment: Not sure if the where clause/filtering is implemented correctly. "relationship_type" is in the "user_services" table, not "services" table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Mmm, I'm not on a PC right now, but a more elegant way would be to add `has_many :check_user_services, { class_name: :UserService }, -> { where relationship_type: 'check' }` and then `has_many :checks, through: :check_user_services, source: :service, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: When I do User.find(1).check_user_services, I see the query "SELECT "user_services".* FROM "user_services"  WHERE "user_services"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]", so the where clause filtering the relationship_type isn't taking into effect for some reasons...

Comment: Ohh, I see, the lambda goes before the options hash. It should be `has_many :check_user_services, -> { where relationship_type: 'check' }, class_name: :UserService`

Comment: YESSSS THAT'S IT!!! So I'm guessing "has_many: :check_user_services" creates a filtered version of "user_service" table while "has_many: :checks" actually joins user and services model together. Somewhere along those lines?